# Playing Medal Of Honor on LAN?

Tags: medal-of-honor

I would like to know if we can play (multiplayer) MOH 2010 on local network. My friends and I would like to play on the local network we have.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no way to do that :( It has no multiplayer over local network support.